# Xcode and Github not playing together

Tags: ios, xcode, github, xcode7

Trying to use Github for the first time with xCode giving me hard time.

I followed many tutorials but nothing is working for me.

1. using my Github account, created repo for the project
2. opened Xcode and created project, with the git check mark checked
3. opened the source control menu and attached to the Github repo origin/master
4. tried to push and got: "**The local repository is out of date.** Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again." message
5. tried to pull and got: "**"origin/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from.** Please choose a different remote branch." but there is not other branch.
6. tried every thing else and nothing worked

p.s. the first time i did the connection to the remote server i got a popup to enter user and password, now not getting that any more, so i am getting that the connection is not the problem, i can see (or think i can see) the remote repo

Any one got an idea?

Push:

[image]

Pull:

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you use source tree instead. It's a lot more easier.

Comment: 10x, but i'm trying to learn to use Github with Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, fixed the problem!

Notice when you add README or gitignore files when creating a git repo, nothing that i did could push or pull from and to the local copy.

eventually i deleted the Github repo and created a clean repo with no files in it.

Then did the steps from the main repo page and every things worked just fine.

I thing the issue was that i had deferent files in both the Github repo and the local git repo (the local one has the Xcode project files) and it gave me error after error for many things, starting from clean Github repo and getting the gitignore file in advance and adding it to the local project did the trick for me.

10x and i hope that helped

Answer (score 3):

I use the command line most of the time. I can suggest you a better way to do this for your purpose.

Follow below steps :

- Open terminal.
- Type following command

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/EXAMPLE_PROJECT/EXAMPLE.git`

- Go inside the folder and double click on the xcode project file(If the project is already present in the github). Suppose if the project is not in the github then copy and past it inside this folder and double click on .xcodeproj
- Once the project loads in the xcode, click on the "Source Control" on menu bar.
- You will see the commit, push, pull options are visible. Now you should be able to work with git.

Note:

If there is no github account details present in keychain terminal will ask to enter.

If you are using more than one user account in github, then you may have to delete the github account details from key chain. I am not sure how to setup for multiple github account.

Comment: 10x @Aslam,I think that the thing is that the repo in Github is deferent from the project from the local version, i have all the push and pull and all of that enabled in the menu, every thing looks like in the tutorials, it is that nothing is working as in the tutorials, and no one shows what to do if things don't work... your solution is what i already have... ps. it is a new Xcode project, if i clone the repo it is empty except from one file, I need to move the project to the repo as i see it and that is what the push is suppose to do. commit changes local repo and push to Github....

Comment: Can you put the screenshot of the error you are getting?

Comment: sorry it took me some time, but added the images for the alerts for pushing and pulling

Comment: I feel like you are selecting the remote branch. Do a "git fetch" from command line and then select master instead of origin/master. and try. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happens to me from time to time.  Until now I have not really had a good solution that did not involve pulling changes, discarding changes and redoing recent work.  None of these is an ideal solution.

I have the habit of frequently duplicating my project at the file system again and opening up the copy.  This gives me the ability to go back to a prior copy if I hit a bug in XCode that destroys my project.  See my video on Youtube for an example.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY9m2F2i6HY#action=share

I believe this happened to me recently because I duplicated the project at the file system level before committing and pushing my changes to the GIT repository on cloud forge, but as I can see people have the same issue with github.
To recover I opened up my prior version (2017 ProjectOrganizer244_8) and commit and pushed changes.  This was the copy two version prior where I forgot to commit and push.  Then I went to my next version, I could not check in.  But rather than checking that one in I went to my most recent copy (2017 ProjectOrganizer244_10) and I clicked on the icon in the far left panel for Show the Source Code Navigator.  This opens up a panel that looks like this.
[image: Show the Source Code Navigator]

Then I opened the Branches section.  The current branch was selected 'IncreasedEditingWindowSizeAndAddedGoogleAnalytics'.  I right clicked on this branch and selected 'Branch from IncreasedEditingWindowSizeAndAddedGoogleAnalytics'.  I entered a new name for the branch 'ProjectOrganizerContainer'.  Then when I returned to the Source Control menu the next time I selected Commit and Push, the new branch was selected.  I was then able to successfully able to commit and push my changes from version 10 (my most recent copy).  This did not result in any loss of changes and allowed me to continue without losing code changes.  If I do find anything missing, I can copy it over from version 9 and then commit it.  Most importantly to me is that I still see all my revision changes history for the past 113 commits.